# Unable to get Platform Event Enhanced Usage Metrics results using query

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, integration, platform-event

As the Salesforce Summer '23 release is enabled in all environments, I wanted to use "Enhanced Usage Metrics" capability of Salesforce Platform Events. For this I am referring to [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_monitor_enhanced_usage.htm).

When I run the below query:

```
SELECT EventName, EventType, UsageType, Value, StartDate, EndDate 
FROM PlatformEventUsageMetric 
WHERE TimeSegment='Hourly'
```

I am getting below error:

```
No such column 'EventName' on entity 'PlatformEventUsageMetric'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

The documentation says, "**enable enhanced usage metrics**". I am not able to find where should I enable this setting?

Is above "Enhanced Usage Metrics" not yet available to be used? OR Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enhanced Usage Metrics is available in all sandboxes on API version 58 and later.
Before you use it please enable 'enableEnhancedUsageMetrics' field to true in Metadata API using [PlatformEventSettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.244.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_platformeventsettings.htm).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PlatformEventSettings xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <enableEnhancedUsageMetrics>true</enableEnhancedUsageMetrics>
</PlatformEventSettings>
```

As per [release notes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_feature_impact.htm&release=244&type=5), this feature might not be available immediately.

[image]

If you still see error please provide me your sandbox org Id so that I can check further.

Comment: Hi @Vinay, Is it available (can be enabled) in Production?

Comment: This feature is currently available in sandbox, can you confirm if your org is in version 58? If yes it should be available.

Comment: Hi @Vinay, I am not able to deploy above package.xml file to a sandbox using VS Code. What should be my package.xml?

I am getting errors like: 
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'types')
Invalid types definition in manifest file: \manifest\package.xml

Comment: package.xml should be like <types><members>PlatformEvent</members<name>Settings</name>
    </types>
    <version>58.0</version>